# Is you wudhu valid if you put on hair gel/spray on your hair after you complete wudhu?

Tags: wudu, hair

I know that if you have hair gel/hair spray on you, you must get rid of it before you do wudhoo as the water cannot get to your hair.

However, if you do wudhoo first and then put on hair gel/hair spray, is your wudhoo still valid?

Comment: Why should gel invalid a wudu' when we are only asked to wipe over our head(partly)  this would apply in any case so i wonder what the argumentation is even for the case you have gel on your hair.

Comment: 'Gel is like a coating which covers the hair in the same way that henna (mehendi) covers the hair. Therefore, because it is so thick, when one does masah, water does not come into contact with the hair itself. This is because it forms a plastic-like barrier which prevents the water to touch the actual hair and so therefore the masah will be void. In order for the masah to be correct, one must wash all the hair of the head and the beard entirely of the gel so that water can touch the hair, otherwise, the masah will not be valid.'
 http://islamqa.org/hanafi/tafseer-raheemi/51690

Comment: This hadith https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/131 is the evidence allowing to pray with gel on the hair, and even do wudu' with it.

Comment: Then is the above comment that I said wrong?

Comment: If my opinion and interpretation of quran would count yes, but scholars have two different opinions one saying there's no harm, but one should wash it away when performing ghusl(based on the hadith from my comment), the other is what you presented.

Answer (score -2):

Gel/spray doesn't prevent water of wudhoo. You can use them before or after wudhoo with no worry for that, as most fatwas said.